# Query two tables in MySQL to populate a PHP array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am using two queries to select the values from their respective tables, and I want to put them into one array. For example, using the code below, I want to have

```
id, last, first, course1, course2, course3
```

...from

```
$startsem1 and $endsem1
```

...in one array.

```
$startsem1 = $startsem."reg";
$endsem1 = $endsem."reg";
$query = "SELECT id,last,first,course1,course2,course3 FROM $startsem1 
     UNION SELECT id,last,first,course1,course2,course3 FROM $endsem1";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        print_r($row); echo "<br><br>";
    }
```

Comment: if you use a UNION or JOIN would be better, but remember with UNION the column number has to be the same and with JOIN there have to be common field to make it

Comment: You can use a UNION to send both queries at once; you can also run both queries separately, and push the results onto the same array. Really, it depends entirely on the structure of the tables and what you want to use it for.

Comment: I edited my code above. I obtain "id,last,first,course1,course2,course3" from $startsem1 in one array, and "id,last,first,course1,course2,course3" from $endsem1 in another array. How can I put them together? There are several results, so I cannot array push the two together.

Comment: `array_merge()`, or not that, one of PHP's many other tools.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: How can I merge the arrays to my liking when there are several of them that are outputted through the while loop? I am thinking I should use an if loop that searches for matching id's amongst the several arrays, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: I have a solution for this, but I don't think it is elegant.  In a few hours I will be able to post it for you (but I think by then someone will provide an answer that helps both of us).

Comment: So an ID can appear in both query results.  When this happens, will the other fields all be the same, so the records are identical?  If that is not the case, do you want to keep both records or resolve the difference somehow?

Comment: The mysql extension is outdated and on its way to deprecation. New code should use mysqli or PDO, both of which have important advantages, such as support for prepared statements. Note that `or die(mysql_error())` should never appear in production code, as [`die`](http://www.phpfreaks.com/blog/or-die-must-die) breaks HTML output and database error messages should never be revealed to non-admin users as it [discloses too much information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995351.aspx#securityerrormessages_topic2). A better approach would be to properly implement error handling.

Comment: The edit changes the nature of the question. Normally, you should avoid this so as not to invalidate any answers (not an issue here). However, the edit also means that there isn't an obvious issue any longer. Please edit the question to make what you want, and how it differs from what you have, clear and explicit. SO uses a Q&A, rather than a forum, format. Comments aren't suited for discussions, and answers shouldn't appear in comments. Please use SO appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches to merging your data sets:

1. SQL UNION query
2. array manipulation using `array_merge()` or another of the many PHP functions

The post suggests you want to use both at once.  Actually you will select one.

If you use the second, a UNION query doesn't make sense because it produces one result.  You need two separate queries, two results, two arrays.

If you use the first, you may still have array functions (such as `array_merge()`) or loop operations to clean up or resolve data issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $array[] = $row;
    }
echo nl2br(print_r($array, TRUE));
```